# How to create an SSH in gcloud, but keep getting API error

Tags: gcloud, ssh-tunnel, google-cloud-datalab, google-chrome-os

I am trying to set up datalab from my chrome book using the following tutorial https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/tutorials/dataproc-datalab.  However when trying to set up an SSH tunnel using the following guidelines https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/cluster-web-interfaces#create_an_ssh_tunnel I keep on receiving the following error.

> ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) Could not fetch resource:
>    - Project 57800607318 is not found and cannot be used for API calls. If it is recently created, enable Compute Engine API by visiting https://console.developers.google
>   .com/apis/api/compute.googleapis.com/overview?project=57800607318 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our sy
>   stems and retry.

The error message would lead me to believe my "Compute Engine API" is not enabled. However, I have double checked and "Compute Engine API" is enabled.

Here is what I am entering into the cloud shell

```
gcloud compute ssh ${test-cluster-m} \
    --project=${datalab-test-229519} --zone=${us-west1-b}  -- \
    -4 -N -L ${8080}:${test-cluster-m}:${8080}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `${}` is for accessing the local environment variable. You set them in the step before with:

```
export PROJECT=project;export HOSTNAME=hostname;export ZONE=zone;PORT=number
```

In this case would be:

```
export PROJECT=datalab-test-229519;export HOSTNAME=test-cluster-m;export ZONE=us-west1-b;PORT=8080
```

Either try this:

```
gcloud compute ssh test-cluster-m \
    --project datalab-test-229519 --zone us-west1-b  -- \
    -D 8080 -N
```

Or access the enviroment variables with:

```
gcloud compute ssh ${HOSTNAME} \
    --project=${PROJECT} --zone=${ZONE}  -- \
    -D ${PORT} -N
```

Also check the VM you are trying to access is running.

Comment: I checked to make sure the VM was running and then tried the code you suggested. On the first try I got an error "bind: Cannot assign requested address". I found this article https://www.electricmonk.nl/log/2014/09/24/ssh-port-forwarding-bind-cannot-assign-requested-address/ and was able to solve the initial issue. However, now when I run there is no error and it simply sits there blinking in the console.

Comment: Are you running this in the Cloud Shell?

Comment: Yes, I am running cloud shell. Do you think it could have something to do with setting it up on a chrome os. I was able to run the quick start tutorial and get it running that way, but I am still unsure why the method described above does not work.

Comment: I don't think so. Could you check the project selected in the Console is the same as the one you are trying to access?